Handling C# language version specific suggestions in multi-targeted solutions
I'm working with a solution containing over 50 projects targeting both .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 7 (Windows only). I've encountered an issue where the compiler provides syntax suggestions that are incompatible with C# 7.3, such as IDE0090, which requires C# 9 or higher. Implementing these suggestions causes the build to fail for .NET 4.8 targets.
To resolve this, I can manually set the language version or ignore the message code, but these are not viable long-term solutions since we plan to eventually move away from .NET 4.8 and I don't want to lock in a specific language version.
Is there a setting or feature in Visual Studio 2022 that can manage language version detection more accurately? It seems problematic that the compiler fills the Errors List with tons of recommendations based on the maximum language version rather than the minimum required.

Check out conditional compilation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation

@phuzi I don't see that as a solution. Take IDE0090, which suggests removing the type in new expressions without 'var'. I can't use compiler conditions for every object creation, despite the message says "new expression can be simplified"!

These messages are there simply to remind a programmer about a new C# feature.  You know by now, just turn them off.

@HansPassant What about when we remove .NET 4.8? Then it remains turned off. The point is, the compiler is giving a suggestion that is not applicable.

What are the chances that you'll remove .NET 4.8, say to yourself "now we can use new language features" and just suddenly forget to follow up and unset the language version? I'd have thought that quite low probability. If you haven't already, create some area/ticket where you can track ambitions for once you're off of the framework and add a note there to change the language version if you really think you're likely to forget to do so.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, that’s what I did, and that’s what I was hoping to avoid when asking this question: setting the language version for projects and leaving a note somewhere to remove them later. I blame the IDE here. It seems that it runs the compiler independently for each target framework, and the compiler generates its messages without being aware of other targets. ...

... The problem is that errors and warnings are different from code simplification suggestions and should be handled differently. Visual Studio should run the compiler with the minimum language version among targets, or at least provide an option for developers to decide.

You can turn off specific warnings for specific framework targets in multi-targeted projects by adding a conditional property group such as:
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0' ">
  <NoWarn>IDE0090</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>

This will turn off the IDE0090 warning for the net7.0 build.
It's not ideal, but does mean that you don't need to change the source code.

As I expected, this didn't change anything because the message is not appearing for .NET 4.8. In the "Project" column of the Errors List, it's explicitly stated that the message is intended for .NET 7. When an issue relates to both target platforms, it lists both.

@saastn Did you try using the other target? I've updated my answer to show how to turn the warning off for NET 7.0. You should put in the target to suppress the warning for.

Well, I know that it will work, but I don't want to do that. Most of these are fixes that I can't apply yet, not that I prefer not to apply. If I turn them off, they will not appear even if we remove .Net 4.8, until we upgrade to .NET 8 or above.


I can manually set the language version or ignore the message code, but these are not viable long-term solutions

Use <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>, it will allow every supported C# version to be used, regardless of whether you're using .Net Core or .Net Framework. Most syntax-level features are on the compiler side, not on the runtime side.

You can export the .editorconfig file to the directory of your solution and configure different language versions and analysis settings as needed like this:
root = true
# Set the language version to C# 7.3 by default
[*.cs]
dotnet_language_version = 7.3
# Set the language version to the latest for the.cs file of the.NET 7.0 project
[*.csproj]
dotnet_language_version = latest
[*.csx]
dotnet_language_version = latest

Or you can configure the language version of projects based on their project directory:
[Net7Project/**/*.cs]
dotnet_language_version = latest

